# Access Two Different Table Data in a Single Android Class, from Azure Mobile Service Local Database Getting Error

Tags: android, mysql, azure, azure-mobile-services

1.I am Using Two different Azure Local Database Tables in My android Application then Sync to Azure Database.

2.Whenever **I am Using two Different Local Database Table Credentials Using In Single Class, i am getting Null Pointer Exception**.

**Error Logcat:**

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.localstore.MobileServiceLocalStoreException: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 11:23:38.666 4742-5196/com.knowledgeflex.task W/System.err:     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
02-08 11:23:38.666 4742-5196/com.knowledgeflex.task W/System.err:     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
02-08 11:23:38.666 4742-5196/com.knowledgeflex.task W/System.err:     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
02-08 11:23:38.666 4742-5196/com.knowledgeflex.task W/System.err:     at com.knowledgeflex.task.Unit_Activity$6.doInBackground(Unit_Activity.java:1071)
02-08 11:23:38.666 4742-5196/com.knowledgeflex.task W/System.err:     at com.knowledgeflex.task.Unit_Activity$6.doInBackground(Unit_Activity.java:1058)
02-08 11:23:38.666 4742-5196/com.knowledgeflex.task W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-08 11:23:38.666 4742-5196/com.knowledgeflex.task W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-08 11:23:38.686 4742-5196/com.knowledgeflex.task W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
```

UnitActivity.class

```
 private MobileServiceSyncTable<TaskTable> mToDoTable;
 private MobileServiceSyncTable<TasKUnitManagementTable>mToDoTablemgmtTable;
 private MobileServiceClient mClient;


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.unit_activity);


        try {
            // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided

            // Mobile Service URL and key
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "********",
                    "************",
                    this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());





            // Offline Sync LOCAL DATABASE TABLE
            mToDoTable =mClient.getSyncTable("TaskTable",TaskTable.class);

             mToDoTablemgmtTable=mClient.getSyncTable("TasKUnitManagementTable",TasKUnitManagementTable.class);

            //Init local storage
            initLocalStore().get();
            initLocalStore_1().get();





            // Load the items from the Mobile Service
            //  refreshItemsFromTable();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            Log.i("Oncreate", "There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL......!");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.i("Oncreate", "Exception Occur......!");
        }

}
```

Help me how to Access two Different Azure Database Local tables in a Single Class in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that this issue is due to how you are using initLocalStore(), in particular calling it twice.

If we look at the code for initLocalStore from our quickstart it serves a few functions:

1. creating a SQLiteLocalStore
2. defining a table on that store
3. initializing the sync context with that store

You should create one SQLiteLocalStore, define as many local tables as you need on it, and initialize the sync context.  I've demonstrated this with some code below.

```
MobileServiceSyncContext syncContext = mClient.getSyncContext();

if (syncContext.isInitialized())
    return null;

SQLiteLocalStore localStore = new SQLiteLocalStore(mClient.getContext(), "OfflineStore", null, 1);

Map<String, ColumnDataType> tableDefinition = new HashMap<String, ColumnDataType>();
tableDefinition.put("id", ColumnDataType.String);
tableDefinition.put("text", ColumnDataType.String);
tableDefinition.put("complete", ColumnDataType.Boolean);

localStore.defineTable("ToDoItem", tableDefinition);

Map<String, ColumnDataType> nameTableDefinition = new HashMap<String, ColumnDataType>();
nameTableDefinition.put("id", ColumnDataType.String);
nameTableDefinition.put("name", ColumnDataType.String);

localStore.defineTable("NameTable", nameTableDefinition);

SimpleSyncHandler handler = new SimpleSyncHandler();

syncContext.initialize(localStore, handler).get();
```